# Godaddy Cron Job Running every seconds in cpanel

Tags: codeigniter, cron, cpanel, server

I need to load a file every seconds, which means, there is not a determinate time of the day.
I am using cPanel to run the CronJob and the task (the wget) is already working fine and I am just having trouble with the time schedules.

```
I have tried:

Minute  Hour  Day  Month Weekday 
*/1     *      *    *     *
```

Answer (score 0):

```
running every minute:    
Minute  Hour  Day  Month Weekday 
   *     *      *    *     *
```

it seems a bit odd why you run it every second. Cron job cannot be used to schedule a job in seconds interval. i.e You cannot schedule a cron job to run every 1 seconds. The alternative is to write a shell script that uses ‘sleep 1′ command in it.

```
$ cat every-1-second.sh
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
 /home/ramesh/backup.sh
 sleep 1
done
```

Comment: where i write a shell script ?

Comment: you need to write the shell script in the your server and set it to crontab there. Please have a look at http://linuxcommand.org/writing_shell_scripts.php

Comment: can you explain me in detail or give me some example?